# Can't get android to write GeoPoint GPS coordinate data to a file correctly

Tags: android, kml

Im currently writing some software for android that takes gps data in the form of an ArrayList of GeoPoints and writes it to a KML file. The rest of file is created fine, but when the gps data is written to the file in the following way:

```
for(int i=0; i < geoPoints.size(); i++){    
    writer.write(geoPoints.get(i).getLatitudeE6());
    writer.write(", ");
    writer.write(geoPoints.get(i).getLongitudeE6());
    writer.write("\n");
}
```

The output of file is random characters:

```
ꗺ, 繿
ꔚ, 练
鬅, 眑
```

If I change the loop to convert it to a String:

```
for(int i=0; i < geoPoints.size(); i++){    
    writer.write(Integer.toString(geoPoints.get(i).getLatitudeE6()));
    writer.write(", ");
    writer.write(Integer.toString(geoPoints.get(i).getLongitudeE6()));
    writer.write("\n");
}
```

Then the output is almost correct, but there isn't a decimal place?

```
-45570790, 167608003
-45571713, 167608345
-45572973, 167606660
```

Can anyone help me find that pesky decimal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

E6 means its lat * 1E6, so for it to look like -45.57 vs -45570790 you need to divide by 1E6.

```
for(int i=0; i < geoPoints.size(); i++){    
    writer.write(Integer.toString(geoPoints.get(i).getLatitudeE6() / 1E6));
    writer.write(", ");
    writer.write(Integer.toString(geoPoints.get(i).getLongitudeE6() / 1E6));
    writer.write("\n");
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I knew that it would only be something simple!